# How to checkout files from branch with wildcard path spec?

Tags: git

I'm unable to checkout files using wildcards, as described on the [git-scm page](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary.html#def_pathspec), from a specific refspec . Describing the issue with an example.

Creating a repository with java and c files:

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline
d62e124f02e9ec6e2848ccc8db05bb37db167281 All files

$ git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD .
c/one/first.c
c/two/second.c
java/one/first.java
java/two/second.java
```

Removing the java files:

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline
97b2ffbdd79f924ca27d0404c612b93feee7f492 Removed java files
d62e124f02e9ec6e2848ccc8db05bb37db167281 All files

$ git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD .
c/one/first.c
c/two/second.c
```

Trying to checkout the deleted java files, from the previous commit:

```
$ git checkout d62e124f -- '*.java'
error: pathspec '*.java' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Comment: `'*.java'` matches files *in the top tree* whose name ends in `.java`.  Your files are in `java/one/` and `java/two/`, so presumably you want `'**/*.java'`.

Comment: @torek doesn't work. According to that _git-scm_ link `*` should match against paths as well.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, when you do `git checkout d62e124f -- '*.java'`, git uses the current working tree to expand `*.java`, *not* `d62e124f`. As you have just deleted all the files, it matches nothing.

Doing

```
git restore --source d62e124f '*.java'
```

works, as git then uses the correct ref to expand the wildcard.

`git restore` is only available since 2.23.0, before that you can use:

```
git ls-files d62e124f '*.java' | xargs git checkout d62e124f
```